# Bindings cannot contain assignments when using [disabled]

Tags: angular

[image]

When I using [] for disabled this error occurs.

[image]

Comment: why do you assign empty string to first name inside the 'disabled' ?

Comment: your `=` i.e. `assignment` should be replaced with `==` i.e. `condition check`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you please try this I hope it works,

```
<input matInput type=text [(ngModel)]="this.CustomerDetails[0].firstname" name="firstname" [disabled]="this.CustomerDetails[0].name != '' ? true : false">
```

if you do like this it continuously call that function and there is a chances of memory leak

```
<input matInput type=text [(ngModel)]="this.CustomerDetails[0].firstname" name="firstname" [disabled]="functionToCheckTrueOrFalse()">
```

Comment: shouldnt you use a '?' after `this.CustomerDetails[0]?.name` in the Template? Otherwise it will throw an error in case the index [0] has no **name** Property.

Comment: Yes, we can, It is a good practice to write '?' before accessing the value because it will throw an error in case there is no 'name' property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the check on the template just add a function on the component.ts to to check the condition and return  a boolean as a result

```
CheckName(){
 if(this.CustomerDetails[0].name != ''){
    return true; 
 }
 return false;
}
```

and bind the function on the template

```
<input [disabled]="CheckName()" id="name" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular `[disabled]` is used to disable the element. So we have to pass condition into it which will either return true or false and based on that it will disable the element. But you are trying to assign it with an empty string or you did it by mistake.

> **So make it like:**

```
<input matInput type=text [value]="" [(ngModel)]="this.CustomerDetails[0].firstname
name="firstname" [disabled]="this.CustomerDetails[0].name">
```

So now it will disable the input textbox if the `firstname` has a value else it will keep enabled.